# GUI to set up cron jobs

Tags: centos, cron

I need to set up and schedule cron jobs on the server.

Is there a Cron tab GUI that I can access from the server remotely using a web URL ?

My server is a centos machine and local is ubuntu.

Also, good sources/links I can refer to in case that isn't possible?

I have seen this

http://alseambusher.github.io/crontab-ui/
but not sure if it allows remote access through Web UI.

Comment: did you find out any tools like that?